# Mouse acts like scroll wheel

Tags: mouse, touchpad, scrolling

I am having an issue where the main touchpad is acting like a scroll wheel. That is whenever I try to swipe up or down the page or selection scrolls up and down and the actual mouse pointer does not move. Is it a key that I might have accidentally pressed or is it a hardware issue? I have tried restarting but the problem persists. Toshiba S50 Series with Synaptics SMbus touchpad.

Answer (score 0):

Many Toshiba laptops use a key combination to lock and unlock the touch-pad scrolling. Without knowing the full model you are using, I am going to guess that they have stuck with the same combination from the past.

Use <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> to lock or unlock scrolling.